# How to print different output based on different count of digits

Tags: bash

Want parse input what can be up to 4 digits. Want get output like:

```
from `1234` want get `12 34`
from `123`  want get `01 23`
from `12`   want get `00 12`
from `1`    want get `00 01`
```

e.g parse the number form back.

Have this:

```
case "$1" in
????) sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)$/\1 \2/' <<< "$1" ;;
???)  sed 's/\(.\)\(..\)$/0\1 \2/' <<< "$1" ;;
??)   sed 's/\(..\)$/00 \1/' <<< "$1" ;;
?)    sed 's/\(.\)$/00 0\1/' <<< "$1" ;;
*) echo "usage: NNNN"; exit 1;;
esac
```

The script works, but not very elegant. It is possible to do it "nicer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf):

```
printf %04d $1 | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)/\1 \2/'
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pure BASH implementation without using any regex:

```
func() { printf -v s "%04d" "$1"; printf "%s %s\n" "${s:0:2}" "${s: -2}"; }

func "124"
01 24
func "1234"
12 34
func "2"
00 02
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
NUMBER=12
printf "%04d" $NUMBER | sed 's/\(..\)\(..\)/\1 \2/'
```

Comment: Yeah, this was the most straightforward thing I could think of.

Comment: Thank you too, unfortunetaly i can accept only one answer and chrisacock asnwered first. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another bash only solution:

```
f=1234
{ read -n2 a; read -n2 b; } <<<$(printf %04d "$f")
echo "$a $b"
```